# upload file to dropBox using /files_put javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to upload a local file to dropbox using http put method ? 
i am uploading a file but it is without body ? (    "bytes": 0 )

how can i add a content to my file ?

my code is the following  :

```
    $scope.uploadHtmlFile = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/test.txt?access_token='+ localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log(data);
        console.log('file uploaded successfully');
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){

    });
}
```

my file is successfully uploaded but with no content ? it is empty !! 
the documentation is a little confusing to me : https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@smarx : i was making an empty HTTP PUT request, and i ended up by solving my issue this way:

```
$scope.uploadHtmlFile = function() {
    var data = "This is a file upload test ";

    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/test.html?access_token=' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
        data: data
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('file uploaded successfully');
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
}
```

thanks for your feedback !

Comment: what is data (i mean type) ? if i want to put file content, how i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anywhere in your HTTP call where you're actually passing a body. It seems like you're making an empty PUT request?

(Or maybe there's just something here about AngularJS that I don't understand, and you're adding a body somewhere else?)