# How can I upload files to dropbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, upload, dropbox

I didn't see any useful **upload in dropbox** example.

Can you help me? I'm using AngularJS.

Comment: What have you tried ?

possible duplicate of [upload file to dropBox using /files\_put javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101651/upload-file-to-dropbox-using-files-put-javascript)

Comment: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/12/writing-a-file-with-the-dropbox-javascript-sdk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their API should allow you to do this using one of the languages they support directly.  The list of [supported languages is here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core).

Comment: Specifcally this endpoint  https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put