# Upload file to Dropbox with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dropbox

I'm trying to upload file to Dropbox with following code. File is successfully uploaded to Dropbox but size gone 0 bytes.

I'm now planning to upload microsoft word and pdf file.

```
    $scope.uploadHtmlFile = function($files) {
        var data = $files;
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/' + $files[0].name + '?access_token=TOKEN',
            data: data
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log('file uploaded successfully');
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error : ' + data);
            console.log('erro file uploaded successfully');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does this have an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101651/upload-file-to-dropbox-using-files-put-javascript

Comment: @Jorg that's correct for html file upload. Now, I'm no word and pdf file uploading.

Comment: Also I think the `param` parameter actually called `data`, which might explain the empty body

Comment: @Jorg sorry, type. it's *data* actually. But file is 0 bytes.

Comment: var data = $files[0]...might help

Comment: @Sheetal can u post as answer? I'll mark as correct answer.

Comment: Done :), please mark it correct...thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$files is an array object, and file will be referred using $files[0].

```
$scope.uploadHtmlFile = function($files) {
        var data = $files[0];
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/' + $files[0].name + '?access_token=TOKEN',
            data: data
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log('file uploaded successfully');
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error : ' + data);
            console.log('erro file uploaded successfully');
        });
    }
```